# Hide all elements that class that contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I have a few `<span>` elements with class `temp_val` that contain a `1` value that I want to hide. These elements are scattered in my html file.

Here is a snippet of my html code:

```
<div class="row" style="float: left; width: 80%; margin-top: 10px; ">
    <strong>                            
        <span class="temp_val">Value1</span>
        <span style='visibility:hidden' class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
    </strong><br>
    <font size="2">
        <img src="assets/images/maps.png" height="12" width="7" style="vertical-align: middle;" >Image1
        <span style='visibility:hidden' class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
        <img src="assets/images/earphone.png" height="12" width="10" style="vertical-align: middle;" >Image2
        <span style='visibility:hidden' class='temp_val_name'>0</span>
        <img src="assets/images/envelope.png" height="11" width="14" style="vertical-align: middle;">Image3
        <span style='visibility:hidden' class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
    </font>   
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery and it's not working:

```
$(".temp_val_name").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '1') {
        $('.temp_val').hide();
    }
});
```

And this was my first jQuery code but still not working:

```
if($('.temp_val_name').text() == '1') {
    $('.temp_val').hide();
}
```

I still have a lot of elements to hide. I only showed you a few. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: @Epodax oops sorry, because it was a suggested tag. I will remove it. sorry.

Comment: Also `<font>`  has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: `if ($(this).text() == '1') $(this).hide();`, surely?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? `temp_val that contain a 1` you mean `value1`.

Comment: you are checking for value of class "temp_val_name" and hiding the element with class "temp_val"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code it should work for you.

```
$(".temp_val_name").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === '') {
        $('.temp_val').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` to filter out elements having the class `temp_val_name` and has the innerText as `1` and hide the element having the class `temp_val`

```js
$(".temp_val_name").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == 1;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="float: left; width: 80%; margin-top: 10px; ">
  <strong>
    <span class="temp_val">Value1</span>
    <span class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
  </strong>
  <br>
  <font size="2">
    <img src="assets/images/maps.png" height="12" width="7" style="vertical-align: middle;">Image1
    <span class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
    <img src="assets/images/earphone.png" height="12" width="10" style="vertical-align: middle;">Image2
    <span class='temp_val_name'>0</span>
    <img src="assets/images/envelope.png" height="11" width="14" style="vertical-align: middle;">Image3
    <span class='temp_val_name'>1</span>
  </font>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you are targeting all the elements not the siblings of `temp_val`.

Comment: This is not working. It's also not working in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
if($(this).html() == '1') {
```

Answer (score 0):

try to give the class name as array

eg:- `temp_val_name[]` in your elements and apply the same in your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvs6q7oa/)

```
$('.temp_val_name').filter(function() {
   return !!($.trim( $(this).text() ) == '1');
}).hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this loop through the body and check for value `1` and if found then hide that span.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("body span").each(function () {
             var val = parseInt($(this).html());
             if($.isNumeric(val) && val == 1){
                $(this).hide()
             }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did not downvote it, just so know you (I am the asker)